# tf.data.Dataset feedable iterator for training and inference

Tags: python, tensorflow, tensorflow-datasets

I have a **TensorFlow** model that uses **tf.data.Dataset feedable** iterators to switch between training and validation. Both dataset share the same structure, that is they have a features matrix and the corresponding labels vector. In order to use the same model and iterator for inference (no labels vector only featurex matrix) I need to ideally supply a zero labels vector. Is there a more efficient and elegant way to use the dataset API for both training (validation) and inference?

In code:

```
training_dataset = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices((X_train, y_train))
validation_dataset = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices((X_validation, y_validation))

handle = tf.placeholder(tf.string, shape=[])
iterator = tf.data.Iterator.from_string_handle(handle, training_dataset.output_types, training_dataset.output_shapes)
features, labels = iterator.get_next()
```

Features and lables are used inside the model as input placeholders. 
In order to switch between dataset I need to create one iterator for each dataset:

```
training_iterator = training_dataset.make_initializable_iterator()
validation_iterator = validation_dataset.make_initializable_iterator()
```

then create the handle

```
training_handle = sess.run(training_iterator.string_handle())
validation_handle = sess.run(validation_iterator.string_handle())
```

And use the `handle` to select which dataset to use, for example:

```
sess.run(next_element, feed_dict={handle: training_handle})
```

Now, what happens if I have inference data with no labels?

```
inference_dataset = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices(X_inference) # NO y values
inferece_iterator = inference_dataset.make_initializable_iterator()
```

If I add this iterator it will throw and exception because "Number of components does not match: expected 2 types but got 1."
Any suggestions?

This post [How to use tf.Dataset design in both training and inferring?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49071212/how-to-use-tf-dataset-design-in-both-training-and-inferring) is related to this question, but tf.data.Dataset does not have an unzip method.

What are the best practices for this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that the first solution proposed by David Parks looks like this, and I think is better than messing with tf.cond in the code.

```
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np

def build_model(features, labels=None, train=False):
    linear_model = tf.layers.Dense(units=1)
    y_pred = linear_model(features)
    if train:
        loss = tf.losses.mean_squared_error(labels=labels, predictions=y_pred)
        optimizer = tf.train.GradientDescentOptimizer(1e-4)
        train = optimizer.minimize(loss)
        return train, loss
    else:
        return y_pred

X_train = np.random.random(100).reshape(-1, 1)
y_train = np.random.random(100).reshape(-1, 1)

training_dataset = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices((X_train, y_train))
training_dataset = training_dataset.batch(10)
training_dataset = training_dataset.shuffle(20)
handle = tf.placeholder(tf.string, shape=[])
iterator = tf.data.Iterator.from_string_handle(handle, training_dataset.output_types, training_dataset.output_shapes)

features, labels = iterator.get_next()
training_iterator = training_dataset.make_one_shot_iterator()

train, loss = build_model(features, labels, train=True)

saver = tf.train.Saver()
init = tf.global_variables_initializer()

sess = tf.Session()
training_handle = sess.run(training_iterator.string_handle())

sess.run(init)
for i in range(10):
    _, loss_value = sess.run((train, loss), feed_dict={handle: training_handle})
    print(loss_value)

saver.save(sess, "tmp/model.ckpt")
sess.close()

tf.reset_default_graph()

X_test = np.random.random(10).reshape(-1, 1)
inference_dataset = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices(X_test)
inference_dataset = inference_dataset.batch(5)

handle = tf.placeholder(tf.string, shape=[])
iterator_inference = tf.data.Iterator.from_string_handle(handle, inference_dataset.output_types, inference_dataset.output_shapes)

inference_iterator = inference_dataset.make_one_shot_iterator()

features_inference = iterator_inference.get_next()

y_pred = build_model(features_inference)

saver = tf.train.Saver()
sess = tf.Session()
inference_handle = sess.run(inference_iterator.string_handle())
saver.restore(sess, "tmp/model.ckpt") # Restore variables from disk.
print(sess.run(y_pred, feed_dict={handle: inference_handle}))
sess.close()
```

Answer (score 0):

If your graph code I assume you are trying to extract a value for labels `y` from the dataset right? At inference time that was probably baked into the tensorflow dependency graph.

You have a few choices here. Probably the easiest solution is to recreate the graph from code (run your `build_graph()` function, then load the weights using something like `saver.restore(sess, "/tmp/model.ckpt")`). If you do it this way you can re-create the graph without the labels `y`. I assume there are no other dependencies on `y` (sometimes tensorboard summaries add dependencies you need to check too). Your problem should now be solved.

However, now that I've written the above comment (which I'll leave as-is because it's still useful information), I realize you might not even need that. At inference time you should not be using the labels anywhere (again, double check tensorboard summaries). If you don't need `y` then tensorflow should not run any of the operations that use `y`. This should include not trying to extract them from the dataset. Double check that you are not asking tensorflow to use your labels anywhere at inference time.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, however the problem is not that I'm using `y` in the graph. With the same graph if I use feed_dict it works correctly (only passing X as input). The error is raised when I try to use the iterator, that expect the underlying dataset to have two components `X` and `y`. So I was wondering, is it possible to use iterator and datasets in **production** both for training and inference, with inference dataset that has *only* `X`?

Comment: At graph runtime it should not be trying to pull the second component from the iterator if that component is unused. At least I expect it to be this way. Perhaps you are rebuilding the graph and trying to extract 2 values from the iterator, in which case a simple python-based `if` statement should solve it. Another solution might be if you explicitly name the dataset elements. This should be something fairly simple, just a detail somewhere. Does the issue occur at graph runtime (at `sess.run`) or when building the graph (e.g. in python land)?

Comment: It happens at graph runtime. Could you please provide an example of your second solution, that is explicitly name the dataset elements?

Comment: This is an question related to naming the elements in the dataset: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48471688/using-tensorflows-dataset-pipeline-how-do-i-name-the-results-of-a-map-oper/48589464#48589464
You might also try implementing a `tf.cond` if it's the graph that's got the error, though I feel like there's a cleaner solution: https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/cond